# Laravel: URL::to('/') port number for localhost not included in db seed files

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am running a local server on port 4567. I am trying to make it so that when my database seeds I save a reference to the home page on my site in my db. However I noticed when I run URL::to('/') in my seeds it only includes "localhost" without the port, but if I include it in my view code it comes out as "localhost:4567". Why is this? How can I fix it, if possibly, without writing if statement conditionals about what production environment I am in? Thank you.

Seed File result of URL::to('/')

```
http://localhost
```

View File result of URL::to('/')

```
http://localhost:4567
```

Comment: you are set `url` variable in **config/app.php** file

Comment: @JayDhameliya maybe you should put this in an answer as this answers his question.. ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Either set APP_URL in env file

```
APP_URL=http://localhost:4567
```

Or set url in config/app.php

```
'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost:4567'),
```

Comment: There may be some cache related issue. You can clear the cache of config by using "php artisan config:clear' command and check again

Answer (score 0):

Many internal functions and third-party libraries use the APP_URL .env var directly or via `config('app.url')`. The better way is to use the URL generator classes that Laravel provides, eg. the `Url` [facade](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/facades#facade-class-reference).

Even so, you'll see different results in Views versus in the CLI, or in Jobs (eg. links in emails). In the web context most of Laravel's URL generation is based on the server/request URL. For example, the `url()` helper calls methods in [Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php#L133) that ultimately use [Illuminate\Http\Request](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php#L92)'s URL methods.

The CLI and Queued Jobs don't have the Request object, so they have to fall back to something else. That's right, configuration.

So, even though links, redirects, and other generated URL's will function perfectly in the web, these can be "broken" (misconfigured ;) outside the HTTP request lifecycle if APP_URL isn't set in your .env, or directly in the app config as [@Sachin Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7182381/sachin-kumar) points out.