# Laravel Project on Nginx Setup Redirect after Login

Tags: laravel, nginx-reverse-proxy

I setup my Laravel project in Nginx using reverse-proxy.

Here is my reverse-proxy.conf for the project

```
    server {
        listen 8090;
        listen [::]:8090;


        access_log /var/log/nginx/localhost.laravel-access.log;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx/locahost.laravel-error.log error;


        location ~ \.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|swf|ico|pdf|mov|fla|zip|rar)$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
        }

        location ^~ / {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_redirect  off;
                proxy_pass http://XXX.XX.X.X:8082/;
        }
}
```

currently the setup is listening to port 8090. so when I access the project, it is on

> XXX.XXX.X.XXX:8090/login

the problem here is, after inputting the login credentials to my project, the port **8090** loses, and I am redirected into the

> XXX.XXX.X.XXX

IP address only.

Thank you

Comment: Whats the url in the form action?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28105113/laravel-urlto-port-number-for-localhost-not-included-in-db-seed-files/45644253

Answer (score 1):

if you can set APP_URL in env file

```
APP_URL=http://localhost:8090
```

Or set url in config/app.php

```
'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost:8090'),
```

then

```
php artisan config:clear
```